# What is the expected number of runs in a shuffled deck of cards?

Tags: probability

Let's assume that we have 26 cards, 13 Red and 13 Black. A run is a maximum contiguous block of cards, which has the same color.

Eg.
(R,B,R,B,...,R,B) has 26 runs.
(R,R,R,...,R,B,B,B,...,B) has 2 runs.

What is the expected number of runs in a shuffled deck of cards?

By intuition, I know that the answer is 14 (The minimum and maximum runs are 2 and 26, and since all cards have the same possibility to be located, the possible runs will be normally distributed with a mean of (2+26)/2= 14).

On top of my intuition, I also want to try to prove the answer by calculation but am not sure how to do this - Could someone give me a hint or guidance?

Thank you.

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2763/16397

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the expected number of runs of same color in a standard deck of cards?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2763/what-is-the-expected-number-of-runs-of-same-color-in-a-standard-deck-of-cards)

Comment: “By intuition I know…” is a dangerous statement. You should write (and think) “By intuition, I suspect…”

Comment: Thank you Thomas for the advice. And yes I saw that one, but that link does not include detailed calculation.

Comment: The calculation has all the necessary details. If you don't understand it, you should specify what parts are confusing to you. EG Do you understand how they used indicator variables? Do you understand the linearity of expectation?  $\quad$ A misconception like "by intuition, the expected value is the average of the min and the max" suggests that you're a novice when it comes to probability. If so, you should explain what you're familiar with.

Comment: This [live Python script](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxFUMtOBCEQvPMVnb0MKNHZGC-bkHjyNzaMAysO0AQaE_9emB2lTqTr0dXYjAEcmUyIvoALCTPBLWNNyw-znc06rl10p8pntdYb9uZic-kPYquxQKYQjzWoVwkeMRV1nudZwrfJCxaj3rUvRoKuhNeaVk3HSFwYNGhQ4F2LmPIywQO0JLEThNSoeX9bzHAFF3uhm-H7msPfcRTjWvyPtuYtNfDz8B6XNdWQOfvXc6R1pNxu5NP09IUuNoeEbZh6s0cFGxvKUzA6Xk4S2o648q54vv-GhBchfgFO72uK&lang=python) does a brute-force random simulation.

Comment: In the [linked duplicate question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2763/16397) when the answer is presented, someone questions whether the fact that the events are not independent, re what the preceding cards were is relevant.  In  the [Linearity of Expectation article](https://brilliant.org/wiki/linearity-of-expectation/), a proof is given that independence of events is **irrelevant**.

Comment: With respect to the comment of @PM2Ring, personally, I consider such *sanity-checking* very helpful.  That is, find some computer programming language that you are comfortable with (e.g. Python, Java, C...).  Then, when you are facing such a problem, you can attempt to run through the $\displaystyle \binom{26}{13} \approx \left[(10)^7\right]$ possible ways that $(13)$ indistinguishable red cards and $(13)$ indistinguishable black cards can be distributed over $(26)$ positions.  ...see next comment

Comment: Personally, I have found that my PC can routinely handle simulations involving less than $\displaystyle(10)^8$ possible distributions.  This then begs the question as to how to sanity-check if the original problem involved a $(52)$ card deck $\displaystyle \left[ ~\text{i.e.} ~\binom{52}{26} \approx 5 \times (10)^{(14)} ~\right]$ distributions.  Since that is too many to simulate, I would have run simulations on card decks of sizes $(10), (20),$ and $(26)$, looking for a pattern in the data.  Then, I would try to explain the pattern, and then consider what this implies for a $(52)$ card deck.