# Can the symmetry of this run-distribution be established without recourse to its explicit formula?

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, permutations, random-walk

Consider all possible arrangements of the sequence $S_k=(\underbrace{1,1,...,1}_{k},\underbrace{2,2,...,2}_{k}),$ where $k\ge 1.$ There's a [neat proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2764/16397), using indicators and linearity of expectation, that the number of maximal runs in an arrangement of $S_k$ chosen uniformly at random has expectation $k+1.$

However, if we let $A(k,r)$ denote the number of arrangements of $S_k$ that contain exactly $r$ maximal runs ($2\le r\le 2k$), then the same result is an immediate consequence of $A(k,\cdot)$ being **symmetrical** about $r=k+1$ for each $k\ge 1.$ So, although there's already a nice proof of the expectation, I'm interested in a simple-as-possible alternative proof by way of proving this symmetry.

Now, the symmetry can be established in a round-about way by noting an obvious one-to-one correspondence between $r$-run arrangements of $S_k$ on the one hand, and on the other hand, $(r-1)$-turn lattice-paths between $(0,0)$ and $(k,k)$ consisting only of NE/EN turns. A paper by Ting Kuo$^\dagger$ derives a general result for the latter, a special case of which gives the following explicit formula for $A(k,r)$:
$$A(k,r)=\begin{cases}
2\dbinom{k-1}{r-3\over 2}\dbinom{k-1}{r-1\over 2}&\text{if $r$ is odd}\\[2ex]
2\dbinom{k-1}{{r\over 2}-1}^2&\text{if $r$ is even}
\end{cases}\quad\quad\text{where }\quad k\ge 1,\quad 2\le r\le 2k.$$

(This is equivalent to a formula given without references at [OEIS A152659](http://oeis.org/A152659).) From the formula it is straightforward, using well-known properties of binomial coefficients, to show that indeed $A(k,r)=A(k,2k-(r-2))$. That is, the required symmetry holds; hence, the expectation of the number of runs is the middle value in $\{2,...,2k\}$, which is $k+1.$

That formula is great, but to me it seems a vast overkill for merely establishing the *symmetry* of $A(k,\cdot)$; hence, my question:

> How might the symmetry of $A(k,\cdot)$ be more-directly established than by recourse to its explicit formula?

$^\dagger$Ting Kuo, [Enumeration of 2D Lattice Paths with a Given Number of Turns](http://www.csroc.org.tw/journal/JOC26_4/JOC26-4-1.pdf), J. of Computers, Vol. 26, No. 4, January 2016.