# How can we maximize the expected number of runs in a shuffled deck of cards?

Tags: combinatorics, expected-value, card-games

Take a standard deck of cards, with 52 cards, 26 red and 26 black. A run is a maximum contiguous block of cards, which has the same color.

So,
(,,,,...,,) has 52 runs.
(,,,...,,,,,...,) has 2 runs.
What is the expected number of runs, $E_{run}$ in a shuffled deck of cards?

We know that the answer to this question is 27. Source: [What is the expected number of runs of same color in a standard deck of cards?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2763/what-is-the-expected-number-of-runs-of-same-color-in-a-standard-deck-of-cards?rq=1)

But what if we don't have 26 red and 26 black? So:

Suppose we have $x$ red and $y$ black cards, where $x+y=52.$ Prove or disprove the following:

$E_{run}$ is maximized when $x=y=26$. If not, find the pair $(x,y)$ that maximizes $E_{run}$ and find max($E_{run})$.

My concern for this problem is that $E_{run}$ may become too computationally complex to calculate when $x \neq y$. Does anybody have a general way to find it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the same method in the answer to the question you linked, the expected number of runs is
$$
1 + 51\cdot \frac{2xy}{52\cdot 51}
$$
Indeed, for each $n\in \{1,\dots,51\}$, the $n^\text{th}$ card is the end of a run if and only if cards number $n$ and $n+1$ are different colors. The probability that two adjacent cards are different colors is $2xy/(52\cdot 51)$; $x$ choices for the red card, $y$ choices for the black card, and $2$ choices for the order they occur. Furthermore, the last card is always the end of a run. By linearity of expectation, you can add up all of these probabilities (plus one for the last card) to get the expected number of runs.

Now, let $\delta=x-26$, so that $y=52-x=26-\delta$. The above simplies to
$$
1+\frac{(26+\delta)(26-\delta)}{26}=1+\frac{26^2-\delta^2}{26}
$$
Clearly, this is maximized when $\delta=0$. This proves that the maximum expected number of runs occurs when $\delta=0$, which means $x=y=26$.